# Show JSON from url in ListView android

Tags: android, json, listview, android-asynctask

How do I show JSON data from a url in a ListView? I have found many examples that do something like this, but it is never what I'm looking for. I want to keep all my classes separate, and I do not want to use libraries.

I can get a String (formatted) like JSON from a url inside an AsyncTask but I cant find out what to do next. How do I insert this data (as JSON) into a ListView?

Comment: What tutorials have you tried, and what code doesn't work for you? And what is wrong with libraries? They make your code so much simpler. AsyncTasks are hard to get correct.

Comment: I wrote a short article a couple of years back about this exact subject: https://smaspe.github.io/2013/08/06/json-listview.html

Comment: one advice, use GSON works most modular and clean way. you will have objects of all item inside List<ModelClass> items in a simple way.!

Comment: @cricket_007 tutorials like [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) (this one includes the deprecated NameValuePair too which isn't that great) have the AsyncTask in the same file. I need to do it without a library for understanding and to make my teacher know I understand.

Comment: The link you gave uses the Apache library, so that directly goes against your statement to not use a library. If you want to make an HTTP Request, then the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html?hl=sl) covers that. That is step 1 of your task. Step 2 - get a JSONObject / Array. Step 3 - Parse that into a ArrayList. Step 4 - Load into an Adapter. Step 5 - Customize the layout of the adapter. Now, you should understand why your question is so broad...

Comment: You are right. Thanks @cricket_007, I will keep trying.

Comment: Want to let @cricket_007 know that your comment with the steps made me rethink everything, and now I did it. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to hear it. It's always best to do smaller, manageable processes, then ask the question about the specific smaller problem that you have an issue with

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` which is bundled with `android sdk`.

Code is simple

for Object

```
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(respString);
```

for array

```
JSONArray arr=new JSONArray(respString);
```

If you want to parse them directly to your `Java Models` you can use libraries like `GSON` or `LoganSquare`.